# Exporting data into Excel based on a predefined template using VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, vba

I have pasted a code snippet below which was written by someone some years ago. This is regarding exporting some data into an excel file based on a template. Can someone please help we with what the below code means as I am not able to figure it out? Thanks in advance.

`_xlTmp = New Excel.Application
_xlTmp.Workbooks.Open(_fileName, , True, , , , , , , True)
Dim xlNewSheet = CType(_xlTmp.Worksheets.Item("SHEET1"), Excel.Worksheet)                                                                                        xlNewSheet.Copy(CType(_xlTmp.Worksheets("SHEET2"), Excel.Worksheet))
xlNewSheet = CType(_xlTmp.Worksheets.Item("SHEET1 (2)"), Excel.Worksheet)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'Opens Excel and stores a reference to Excel process
xlTmp = New Excel.Application 

'Opens the excel file with path '_fileName'
_xlTmp.Workbooks.Open(_fileName, , True, , , , , , , True)

'Stores a reference to Sheet named "SHEET1"
Dim xlNewSheet = CType(_xlTmp.Worksheets.Item("SHEET1"), Excel.Worksheet)

'Copies the refered sheet to sheet named "SHEET2" - replacing it                                                                      
xlNewSheet.Copy(CType(_xlTmp.Worksheets("SHEET2"), Excel.Worksheet))

'Reference to the copied sheet
xlNewSheet = CType(_xlTmp.Worksheets.Item("SHEET1 (2)"), Excel.Worksheet)
```

However, if you use Excel COM you should code in a different way, so you can dispose all objects "referencing something" in Excel. You will also get exceptions if the filename or sheets with given names are not found.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. It was very helpful.